# Using cassandra mapper with UDT in java

Tags: java, cassandra, mapper

I am total novice with cassandra and have a following problem: I defined a simple UDT
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.CqlName;

```
    @CqlName("emailaddress")

public class EmailAddress {
    private String name;
    private String email_address;

    public EmailAddress() {}
    public EmailAddress(String name, String emailAddress) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email_address = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail_address() {
        return email_address;
    }

    public void setEmail_address(String email_address) {
        this.email_address = email_address;
    }
}
```

I have following line in definition for my entity:

....

```
@Frozen
private List<EmailAddress> participants;
```

.....

I created simple Dao with one method save() but when I trying to run it I am getting following error

The CQL ks.table: signature_data.signatures defined in the entity class: com.salesforceiq.graph.sigparser.Signatures declares type mappings that are not supported by the codec registry:
Field: participants, Entity Type: com.salesforceiq.graph.sigparser.EmailAddress, CQL type: UDT(signature_data.emailaddress)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The CQL ks.table: signature_data.signatures defined in the entity class: com.salesforceiq.graph.sigparser.Signatures declares type mappings that are not supported by the codec registry:
Field: participants, Entity Type: com.salesforceiq.graph.sigparser.EmailAddress, CQL type: UDT(signature_data.emailaddress)

I probably miss some annotation for my UDT but I can't figure out which one

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you annotated your UDT class with `@Entity`. See the [Entities](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/mapper/entities/) page of the Cassandra Java driver for an example.

It appears to fail on the `participants` column. Its type isn't supported so you might need to implement a custom codec for it. See the [Custom codecs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/custom_codecs/) page for details. Cheers!

Comment: No I didn't I thought it was annotation for table definitions only. Thanks a lot it worked